# What's Intel Scalable CPU?

Tags: cpu

I spend 20min trying to figure out what is "scalable" in new Xeon CPUs.

Almost all tech articles now are poorly written amateur pulp fiction.

Can someone please tell how are they scalable exactly?

Comment: from what i understand, they are scalable on Intel's end of manufacturing, nothing for the end user.

Comment: No I don't think so. It seems they are scalable in respect to motherboard nodes. But I can't figure how is this different to regular CPUs. I guess they share something between nodes, what regular CPUs dont